# Saving an employee number in Laravel throws error of A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save an employee number as EMP00001 format. I have the following code that I'm using in the controller under store and I'm getting an error of A non-numeric value encountered.

```
 $emp = Employee::create($request->all()+
        ['employee_number' => Employee::max('employee_number') + 1 ]);
        $employee_code =  sprintf ("EMP",'%06d');
        $employee_no = ($employee_code +$emp);
        $employee_no->save();
```

MySQL column for employee_number is varchar.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How can you increment the employee_number when the column type is varchar.You can split it into char and int and then increment the stored int  by 1

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$emp = Employee::create(array_collapse([
$request->toArray(),
['employee_number' =>  preg_replace("|(\d+)|e",
 "$1+1",Employee::max('employee_number'))]
]));
$employee_code =  sprintf ("EMP",'%06d');
$employee_no = ($employee_code +$emp);
$employee_no->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

It throws such error, because `Employee::max('employee_number')` returns a string, it is varchar column type, since you are inserting them in format of `EMP00001`. 
You have set strict type for PHP which is good. 
Try to call it outside the main Query, extract the number, add number to it and do the insertion:

```
$num_employee_max = Employee::max('employee_number');
$num_employee = (int)str_replace('EMP', '', $num_employee_max);
$new_num_employee = $num_employee + 1;
$employee_code = sprintf('EMP%06d',$new_num_employee);
 $sanitized values = $request->all(); //do the proper sanitization instead of this

 $emp = Employee::create( $sanitized values +
        ['employee_number' =>  $employee_code]);
```

**Note:** Avoid inserting non-sanitized values from input directly in database.

Also, sprintf ("EMP",'%06d'); doesn't do a thing. 
see about sprintf: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php